# Notation for formal logical reasoning, premises & conclusions

Tags: logic

Is this notation correct? (Learning basics of logical notation)

∃x∈X: P(x)
∀yP(y) -> O(y)
∴∃x∈X: O(x)

"There exists an element x in a set X with property P."
"For all elements with property P has also property O."
"Therefore there exists an element in the set X with property O."

Comment: Better : "All elements with property P have also property O." Parentheses are useful in order to correctly define the *scope* of quantifiers : $\forall y (Py \to Oy)$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good, but for this site you can [use MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/276406) rather than Unicode special characters.  For this specific notation, use:

```
$$\exists x \in X : P(x)$$
$$\forall y (P(y) \Rightarrow O(y))$$
$$\therefore \exists x \in X : O(x)$$
```

which produces:

$$\exists x \in X : P(x)$$
   $$\forall y (P(y) \Rightarrow O(y))$$
   $$\therefore \exists x \in X : O(x)$$

As for reading this out loud, I would verbalize it as follows:

> $$\exists x \in X : P(x)$$
>   There exists an element $x$ in $X$ for which predicate $P$ of $x$ is true.
>   $$\forall y (P(y) \Rightarrow O(y))$$
>   For all $y$, $P$ of $y$ implies $O$ of $y$.  (Or if I want to be explicit, "For all $y$, predicate $P$ of $y$ implies predicate $O$ of $y$.")
>   $$\therefore \exists x \in X : O(x)$$
>   Therefore, there exists an element $x$ in $X$ for which predicate $O$ of $x$ holds true.